# When Bhairava destroyed the creation of Brahman mere with the great laughter?

Tags: scripture, stotra, bhairava

In the famous [Kaal Bhairava Ashtakam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SE0n7ko_fYU&t=247s) of Adi Shankaracharya we find the verse -

> अट्टहासभिन्नपद्मजाण्डकोशसंततिं 
>   दृष्टिपातनष्टपापजालमुग्रशासनम् । 
>   अष्टसिद्धिदायकं कपालमालिकाधरं 
>   काशिकापुराधिनाथकालभैरवं भजे ॥७॥ 
>   To him whose loud laughter can tear asunder all born of the egg of the Brahma. That fierce ruler whose very sight to is enough to destroy the web of sins. To the granter of eight siddhis, the one one who wears a garland of skulls; I salute the Kaalbhairava, the Lord of the city of Kashi. verse 7

I want to know about the occasion or incident about which Adi ShankarAchArya is talking about. Can anyone provide the incident?

Comment: Adi Shankaracharya is probably talking about all time of Pralay. Bhairav destroys universe by mere laughter this shows how powerful he is.

Comment: It's actually creation of BrahmA and not Brahman... it is saying "padmajAndakosha"..  with padmajA referring to Lord BrahmA

Comment: It could be even Lord Shiva since both of them are same.

Comment: Anurag is right. PadmajAnDakOza is a synonym of bramhAnDa(kOza). It does not refer to brahman or the four-headed brahma.

Comment: @Rickross is right , Padmaja means Padma-ja - lotus-born and Brahma is called Padma Ja. Then his created egg is called Brahmaa-Anda, so it became PadmaJa-anda - the cosmic egg of Brahmaa (usually translated as Universe). And maybe Shankaracharya is talking about piercing of this Brahmaanda. There is a story that Brahmaa creates this egg, then Shiva pierces it to open it , and Vishnu preserves it, and at end Shiv destroys it again. Maybe Shankaracharya is talking about this piercing of egg.

Comment: @AnuragSingh You can answer.

Comment: @Rohit but that story does not speak about Bhairav. And it is a maybe thing. Not exactly sure.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Shiva = Bhairava according to Stotra

Comment: The four-headed brahma created the egg-shaped universe?

Comment: @moonstar sorry, don't have Puranic knowledge.

Comment: I think what the Kalabhairavashtakam is saying is that Kala Bhairava's laugh is powerful enough to destroy everything in the Universe, not that he actually uses his laugh for this purpose.