# Is Kaal Bhairava Ashtakam inauthentic work of Adi Shankar?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, stotra

[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26587/when-bhairava-destroyed-the-creation-of-brahman-mere-with-the-great-laughter#comment76126_26587) a user claiming Kalbhairava Ashtakam is an inauthentic work of Adi Shankaracharya.

As for obvious reasons, works of Vaishnavas on Lord Shiva can be considered inauthentic or can be seen with careful eyes I would like to know the proofs other than of Vaishnavas which prove inauthentic nature of Kalbhairava Ashtakam.

Comment: Why "other than Vaishnavas" ? Bias?

Comment: Then why don't you add Shaivas too? They are also not neutral. They are biased towards Shiva.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma sorry for wrong choice of word. I wanted to read perspectives of those who doesn't say Sri Rudram is not for Shiva, MahaMrityunjai is not for liberation, Mahabharata part where Shiva is shown supreme is interpolated etc. And It is my question. I guess I can ask however I want. :P

Comment: Anyone can say anything.. that does not mean u have to post a question here..@Rohit. You have done it earlier too if i am not wrong.

Comment: Kaala Bhairava ashtak poetry style is same as other works of Shankaracharya . Shankaracharya uses extremely intricate sanskrit poetry and the kaal bhairav ashtak has the same intricacy . Also he has uses very hard to find meters, like in KBAshtak he has used meter of 15×4 syllables , in Saundarya Lahiri he used 17×4 syllables. Other than Shankhar, no one else has done it , at least as far I have seen. Rumour lovers spread whatever comes in their mind, tomorrow they will say that Mahabharat was written by a horse and Ramayan by a butterfly.

Comment: @AnuragSingh You can answer partially.